# How to escape some characters in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have this data in one column in postgresql

```
{
    "geometry":{
        "status":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
            -122.421583,
            37.795027    
        ]          
    },
```

and i using his query

`select * from students where data_json LIKE '%status%' ;`

Above query return results but this one does not

`select * from students where data_json LIKE '%status:%' ;`

How can fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the 2nd one doesn't find a match, there's no `status:` text in the value. I think you wanted:

```
select * from students where data_json LIKE '%"status":%'
```

... however, like most cases where you attempt text pattern matching on structured data this is in general a *terrible* idea that will bite you. Just a couple of problem examples:

```
{
    "somekey": "the value is \"status\": true"
}
```

... where `"status":` appears as part of the *text value* and will match even though it shouldn't, and:

```
{
    status : "blah"
}
```

where `status` has no quotes and a space between the quotes and colon. As far as JavaScript is concerned this is the same as `"status":` but it won't match.

If you're trying to find fields within json or extract fields from json, do it with a json parser. [PL/V8 may be of interest](https://code.google.com/p/plv8js/wiki/PLV8), or the json libraries available for tools like pl/perl, pl/pythonu, etc. Future PostgreSQL versions will have functions to get a json key by path, test if a json value exists, etc, but 9.2 does not.

At this point you might be thinking "why don't I use regular expressions". Don't go there, you *do not* want to try to write a full JSON parser in regex. [this blog entry is somewhat relevant](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

Comment: Can i use hstore for that type of search

Comment: @user194932147 `hstore` is flat, it doesn't have nested keys. You could probably write code to flatten `json` into a `hstore` and ignore/overwrite duplicate keys but it'd (a) be a bit unsafe and (b) require you to do most of the work you'd have to do for a proper json key search anyway. As I said, use PL/V8, PL/Perl, or similar to write a key lookup function or find one somebody else has already written. You can create functional indexes on the key lookup function.